# How to enable ExternalData Sources in Salesforce Developer Edition?

Tags: lightning-connect

I want to enable a **ExternalData Sources** in my Developer Edtion for creating External Objects, Is this possible to enable ExternalData Sources in developer environment or need to get a assistance from Salesforce support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can open a case with salesforce support and ask them to enable the perm: External Objects Beta.

Or You can provide me the ORG ID and I can verify if I can enable it for your Developer edition.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is my       ORG ID : 00D90000000pw4Z

Comment: I have enabled it for your free Developer edition.Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your great support now it showing the ExternalDataSources and External Objects in my DeveloperEdition..

Comment: @varun guruvugari Can you enable this feature in this ORG ID:00D90000000pYFE because me to trying this feature.It will be very helpful for me .

Comment: @ManojChandran: I have enabled it.It is a pilot feature which is in Beta version, so I would recommend users to wait until it open for all users.

Comment: There is picklist field called Type but there is no value for it.Since its mandatory i need to select some value but im not getting any value.Is there anyother way to select it?

Comment: @varun guruvugari- Can You Please enable this feature for this Org Id: 00D90000000mHqz

Answer (score 0):

External Objects (Lightning Connect in marketing terms) is now generally available in Winter 15 (API 32.0). You can find it under `Build > Develop > External Objects`.

[image]